# Add custom fields to WooComerce product setting pages in the shipping tab

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

Is it possible to do add some extra fields in WooCommerce products pages shipping tab settings in backend, as I need to add something like 12 custom fields.

I have tried to find some related hooks without success. The only way that I have found was over attributes, but it was not a convenient solution…

How can I add custom fields to WooComerce product setting pages in the shipping tab?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is possible and you will get this (here I have set to custom text fields):

[image]

Here is the code:

```
// Add custom fields to product shipping tab
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_shipping', 'add_custom_shipping_option_to_products');
function add_custom_shipping_option_to_products(){
    global $post, $product;


    echo '</div><div class="options_group">'; // New option group

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'          => '_custom_text_field1',
        'label'       => __( 'My Text Field one', 'woocommerce' ),
        'placeholder' => 'something',
        'desc_tip'    => 'true',
        'description' => __( 'Enter the custom value here.', 'woocommerce' ),
        'value'       => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_custom_meta_field1', true ),
    ) );

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'          => '_custom_text_field2',
        'label'       => __( 'My Text Field two', 'woocommerce' ),
        'placeholder' => 'something',
        'desc_tip'    => 'true',
        'description' => __( 'Enter the custom value here.', 'woocommerce' ),
        'value'       => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_custom_meta_field2', true ),
    ) );
}

// Save the custom fields values as meta data
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_custom_shipping_option_to_products' );
function save_custom_shipping_option_to_products( $post_id ){

    $custom_text_field1 = $_POST['_custom_text_field1'];
    if( isset( $custom_text_field1 ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_custom_meta_field1', esc_attr( $custom_text_field1 ) );

    $custom_text_field2 = $_POST['_custom_text_field2'];
    if( isset( $custom_text_field2 ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_custom_meta_field2', esc_attr( $custom_text_field2 ) );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested on WooCommerce 3+ and works

Comment: Hi, Thanks and it will work also automatically in plugins like compare?

Comment: Hi, and how is possible to have one field divided to more like the dimensions which are already there? And is possible to edit the text of the existing fields names?

Comment: And how is also possible to set that the numbers are stored in decimal form?

Comment: And how to show them in the additional information tab on the product page with correct units?

Comment: Hi, I know that this part works, thanks, I have already implemented it. Ok then I will put a new question thanks, but please is possible to show me how can I modify one field that is similar to existing dimension field?

Comment: I accept it but please is possible to show me how can I modify one field that is similar to existing dimension field and how to set that the numbers are stored in decimal form? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for it. Next time I will put it more clearly.

Comment: @Alfista Just saying because more clear and detail is the question, more chances you get to have a working and complete answer.

Comment: I understand. I make a mistake in that but next time I will do it correctly. Thanks and hope you can help me to change the code to be as I need. Thanks again.

Comment: Please is possible to show me how can I modify one field that is similar to existing dimension field and how to set that the numbers are stored in decimal form? Thanks.