# WooCommerce get_attribute returning null

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, product

I am trying to get the value of 2 specific custom product attributes however I am not able to return any value.

Below is a trimmed down version of my code as a lot is irrelevant to this issue.

Within my Product I have set a custom attribute with the name `carrier` and the value `AA12345`. I have also set the attribute `template` with the value `BB67890`. I'm really not sure what I am doing wrong here.

```
foreach( $order-> get_items() as $item_key => $item_values ):

    $item_id = $item_values->get_id();
    $item_name = $item_values->get_name();
    $item_type = $item_values->get_type();
    $product_id = $item_values->get_product_id(); // the Product id
    $wc_product = $item_values->get_product(); // the WC_Product object
    ## Access Order Items data properties (in an array of values) ##
    $item_data = $item_values->get_data();
    $product_name = $item_data['name'];
    $product_id = $item_data['product_id'];
    $variation_id = $item_data['variation_id'];
    $quantity = $item_data['quantity'];
    $tax_class = $item_data['tax_class'];
    $line_subtotal = $item_data['subtotal'];
    $line_subtotal_tax = $item_data['subtotal_tax'];
    $line_total = $item_data['total'];
    $line_total_tax = $item_data['total_tax'];
    $order_id = $item_data['order_id'];

    if ($product_id == 37) {
    } else if ($product_id == 50) {
    // Get Poduct attributes
    $p = wc_get_product( $product_id );
    $patt_carrier = $p->get_attribute( 'carrier' );
    $patt_template = $p->get_attribute( 'template' );
        $product_type = "PICKANDPACK";
        $postData['bundles'][] = [ 
            'type' => $product_type,
            'items' => [
                'bom' => [
                [
                    'type' => 'CARD',
                    'stockId' => $item_data['sku'],
                    [
                        'type' => 'CARRIER',
                        'quantity' => '1',
                        'stockId' => $patt_carrier,
                        'metadata' => [
                            'template' => $patt_template,
                        ]
                    ],
                    ],
                ],


        ];
    }
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was mostly working, there was just 2 small errors and a redundancy:

- A missing closing `]` in your `$postData` array,
- To get the product SKU you should use `$product->get_sku()` instead of `$item_data['sku']`,
- To the WC_Product object was already available in `$item_values->get_product()`.

The part to get the your product attributes values is correct.

So your working (tested) code should be:

```
foreach( $order-> get_items() as $item_key => $item_values ):
    $product_id = $item_values->get_product_id(); // the product id
    $product = $item_values->get_product(); // <== the WC_Product object
    $product_sku = $product->get_sku(); // <== the product sku

    if ($product_id == 37) {
    } else if ($product_id == 50) {

        // Get Poduct attributes (==> working)
        $patt_carrier = $product->get_attribute( 'carrier' );
        $patt_template = $product->get_attribute( 'template' );

        $product_type = "PICKANDPACK";
        $postData['bundles'][] = [
            'type' => $product_type,
            'items' => [
                'bom' => [
                    [
                        'type' => 'CARD',
                        'stockId' => $product_sku, // <== The sku
                        [
                            'type' => 'CARRIER',
                            'quantity' => '1',
                            'stockId' => $patt_carrier,
                            'metadata' => [
                                'template' => $patt_template,
                            ]
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ], // <== one was missing
        ];
    }
        // Testing the raw output
        echo '<pre>'; print_r( $postData ); echo '</pre>';
endforeach;
```

---

**USING CUSTOM FIELDS (alternative)**

> **Another way to do it**, should be using custom fields instead of product attributes (if you don't need them to be displayed in the "Additional information" product tab).

How to do it:
[Add custom fields to WooComerce product setting pages in the shipping tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45212221/add-custom-fields-to-woocomerce-product-setting-pages-in-the-shipping-tab/45213169#45213169)

Comment: Thank you for answering this @LoicTheAztec. This helped tremendously! I did consider the custom fields route however I didn't want to add extra dependencies to the plugin as it will be used in many sites.