# Add Custom field to product data to admin shipping section in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields

I would like to add a custom field at the place marked in the image. But how do I place a field there?

[image]

This field should be under the shipping methods of a product in the admin side of the website.

I tried looking at the ACF field location rules, for example: Taxonomy is equal to product_cat.
Not the exact one stated above but some of these rules I tried. But unfortunately it did nothing.

Comment: ACF doesn't allow adding fields to WooCommerce Admin Product data settings… For that, you can use hand coded custom fields like [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45212221/add-custom-fields-to-woocomerce-product-setting-pages-in-the-shipping-tab).